Can anyone open this corrupt (?) M4A file (and convert it to an MP3 or something that I can use)?
I was just looking through an old harddisk, and I found some (apparently) M4A files that I'd love to listen to (it's recordings of me and a friend playing guitar). But neither VLC nor any other app that I tried seems to be able to open it.
https://josh.ch/files/road-trippin.m4a
I even tried FFMPEG and FFPROBE, and both resulted in this:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x12be06fb0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x12be06fb0] moov atom not found
rhcp - road trippin-1.m4a: Invalid data found when processing input

The files are contained in a WhatsApp backup that I created a few years ago with some macOS software (I don't remember the name anymore).
Any help is appreciated!

Have you tried an editing video software like open shot, you might be able to place the file in there

It's < 2 MB, so even if it contained highly compressed audio, it would be only  some seconds long. As is, it contains no header info, though it ends with MP1... EVLZ.
